# PhoneGap - Local Storage

Tags: cordova

I'm developing my first app with phonegap and have a basic question: My app includes mostly text and pictures. Both do not change very often, so I would like to store them on the device rather downloading them every time the user opens the app.
My questions:

- Does the app automatically detect if there is not enough space for the images on the device?
- I want to fetch the data from a MySQL-database; is there any kind of push notification to tell the app that it should update the data? Or is it better to check for updates in a certain time interval?

Thanks

Comment: did you solve your problem #1.? Im looking for the same implementation.
#2. You have to implement the push notification plugin. https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git Also recode for your purpose. because check for updates with a time interval is not the best way because it drains the battery very fast. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: @Schwertfisch you can check the answer for freespace checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for free space using the following code and FILE plugin

```
cordova.exec(
    function(freeSpace) {
      alert('reported free space is ' + freeSpace);
    },
    function() {
      alert('failed');
    }, 
    "File", "getFreeDiskSpace", []
  );
```

View this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23559931/604097) for more details.

For your 2nd problem, so far I know you will need to write custom plugin to check for any change on server using some background service. Or you can check changes on server on app startup. I think it'll be better to implement a `SYNC` option inside app to synchronize your data between server and app rather than this background service.